# Show that $gK = Kg$ for every $g \in G$ knowing that is true for every coset representative.

Tags: group-theory, permutations

The original question is this:

> Let $G = S_4$ and let $K = \{ 1, (1,2)(3,4), (1,3)(2,4), (1,4)(2,3) \}$. Determine the cosets of $K$ in $G$. Conclude that $gK = Kg$ for all $g \in G$.

I used sagemath to compute the cosets, and verified that for the class representatives the software chose this is true (like $(1,2) K = K (1,2)$). But how can this be extended to all $g \in G$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a property of an arbitrary group. Choose some $g\in G$. Let $a$ be a coset representative of $gK$ so that you already know $aK=Ka$. Then $g\in aK$ by assumption, i.e., $a^{-1}g\in K$. So $a^{-1}gK=K$, i.e., $gK=aK$. We also have $g\in Ka$, i.e, $ga^{-1}\in K$. So $Kga^{-1}=K$, i.e., $Kg=Ka$. Putting it all together: $gK=aK=Ka=Kg$.